# How do Display Custom PopupMenu in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jpopupmenu

`JComboBox` displays a List on click. Instead of the list, I want to display a `JPopupMenu`.
In the following code the event is triggered but the popup doesnt show up. Why?

```
JComboBox box = new JComboBox();

box.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
   @Override
   public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {      
     popupMenu.show(box, 0, box.getHeight());
   }
   ...
});
```

Comment: You can associate a `JPopupMenu` with any `JComponent`. Why not make a pseudo `JComboBox`?  A `JTextField` and a `JButton` and when you click on the button, a `JPopupMenu` appears.

Comment: *Why?* - yes, the question is why do you want to do this? A JComboBox is designed for a specific purpose, to display a list of items added to the combo box. If you want to do something different then you create your own custom component. Without knowing why you would want to do something like this we can't offer an alternative suggestion other than don't try to fit a square box in a round hole.

Comment: I have a JComboBox nearby and want to have the User have exactly the same user experience. So the Button has to look exactly like the ComboBox. Im using Nimbus LAF and it is quite hard to create a Button looking like that. Thats why I discarded the approach @Abra and camickr are suggesting.

Comment: You wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61249485/how-do-display-custom-popupmenu-in-jcombobox#comment108365102_61249485): _Im using Nimbus LAF and it is quite hard to create a Button looking like that._ Maybe this will help: [Nimbus Defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)

Comment: But a button and a combo box SHOULD look different. They should NOT have the same user experience. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively one can use a mouseListener. Due to a JDK-bug
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4144505
one has to add the mouseListener to all Descendants like that:

```
 MouseAdapter comboPopupAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        popupMenu.show(box, 0, box.getHeight());
      }
    };
    box.addMouseListener(comboPopupAdapter);
    for (Component c : box.getComponents()) {
      c.addMouseListener(comboPopupAdapter);
    }
```